Using .gitlab-ci.yml along with script
I would be grateful if someone could clarify something for me. I have two servers:
GitLab Server: Repositories
GitLab Runner: Runner + Docker

On my GitLab server I have created a project with some code. In the root directory of my project, I have placed two files, .gitlab-ci.yml and Dockerfile.
The content of the .gitlab-ci.yml file is as follows:
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
before_script:
  - mkdir -p node_modules/
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - main
  script:
    - mkdir -p node_modules/
    - cd /data/containers/SOURCE/
    - git clone http://IP/project/test.git
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - main
  script:
    - cd /data/YAML

The docker-compose.yml file is located at /data/YAML directory on the GitLab runner server. If I add the following lines to the .gitlab-ci.yml file, then will this cause docker compose to use the docker-compose.yml file located in the /data/YAML directory?
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - main
  script:
    - cd /data/YAML
    - docker compose build --no-cache
    - docker compose up -d

Any idea welcomed.
Cheers.
I want to know if GitLab Runner can execute the commands in script section on GitLab Runner server?
